# Comparing navigation algorithms

Tags: nav2, base-local-planner, global-planner

I am new to Nav2 stack and currently there are a bunch of navigation plugins to choose from (https://navigation.ros.org/plugins/index.html). I am interested in how to choose available algorithms from those in "**Planners**" and "**Controllers**" sections. For example, how to know pros & cons of *NavFn* planner compared with *SmacPlanner*. How to know pros & cons of *DWB* controller against *TEB* controller. Is there any site clarify something like this?

Thank you,

Peera

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a paper for that: https://arxiv.org/pdf/2307.15236.pdf

> S. Macenski, T. Moore, DV Lu, A. Merzlyakov, M. Ferguson, From the
> desks of ROS maintainers: A survey of modern & capable mobile robotics
> algorithms in the robot operating system 2, Robotics and Autonomous
> Systems, 2023